# google analytics event not recorded by GA

Tags: google-analytics

On a given page, in addition to normal GA call, I am making an event call, and what we call a "phantom URL" call.  The normal call seems to be recorded in GA, I can run a report on it, but neither event call, nor a "phaontom url" call are recorded.

Here's the javascript that I place on the page

```
    <!-- analytics events --><script type="text/javascript">$(document).ready(function() {_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'interview', 'ask', 'labelone', 2]);_gaq.push(['_trackPageview', '/phantom/interview/ask']);});</script><!-- end analytics events -->
```

I can see in FireBug 3 requests to __utml.gif, all 3 look OK to me:

Regular call (I can see the requests in GA)

```
http://www.google-analytics.com/__utm.gif?utmwv=4.7.2&utmn=59651520&utmhn=www.xxxmysitexxx.com&utmcs=UTF-8&utmsr=1920x1200&utmsc=24-bit&utmul=en-us&utmje=1&utmfl=10.1%20r53&utmdt=xxxmysitexxx.com&utmhid=787103110&utmr=0&utmp=%2Finterview%2Femail%2Flovedone%3FquestionIds%3D2%26questionIds%3D3&utmac=UA-12946710-1&utmcc=__utma%3D99976543.1556653907.1279057537.1279057537.1279123546.2%3B%2B__utmz%3D99976543.1279057537.1.1.utmcsr%3D(direct)%7Cutmccn%3D(direct)%7Cutmcmd%3D(none)%3B
```

Event call [utme=5(interview*ask*labelone)(2)] (I don't see any events in GA)

```
http://www.google-analytics.com/__utm.gif?utmwv=4.7.2&utmn=505023631&utmhn=www.xxxmysitexxx.com&utmt=event&utme=5(interview*ask*labelone)(2)&utmcs=UTF-8&utmsr=1920x1200&utmsc=24-bit&utmul=en-us&utmje=1&utmfl=10.1%20r53&utmdt=xxxmysitexxx.com&utmhid=787103110&utmr=0&utmp=%2Finterview%2Femail%2Flovedone%3FquestionIds%3D2%26questionIds%3D3&utmac=UA-XXXXX-X&utmcc=__utma%3D99976543.1556653907.1279057537.1279057537.1279123546.2%3B%2B__utmz%3D99976543.1279057537.1.1.utmcsr%3D(direct)%7Cutmccn%3D(direct)%7Cutmcmd%3D(none)%3B&gaq=1
```

"phantom URL call (searching for "phantom" in the GA report returns no result)

```
http://www.google-analytics.com/__utm.gif?utmwv=4.7.2&utmn=358843229&utmhn=www.xxxmysitexxx.com&utmcs=UTF-8&utmsr=1920x1200&utmsc=24-bit&utmul=en-us&utmje=1&utmfl=10.1%20r53&utmdt=xxxmysitexxx.com&utmhid=787103110&utmr=0&utmp=%2Fphantom%2Finterview%2Fask&utmac=UA-XXXXX-X&utmcc=__utma%3D99976543.1556653907.1279057537.1279057537.1279123546.2%3B%2B__utmz%3D99976543.1279057537.1.1.utmcsr%3D(direct)%7Cutmccn%3D(direct)%7Cutmcmd%3D(none)%3B&gaq=1
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, figured out the problem.  My _gaq didn't have an account set on it, so 2nd and 3rd calls were goingout with

```
utmac=UA-XXXXX-X
```

Code should look something like this:

```
var _gaq = _gaq || [];
_gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-ACCOUNTNUMBER-1']);
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'interview', 'ask']);
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview', '/phantom/interview/ask']);
```

Comment: This fixed a problem of mine using Google Tag Manager w/ an older 3rd party script that relied on _gaq.